# Does everything on the World Wide Web use REST?

Tags: api, rest, networking, web-deployment

I decided to start learning web development and for some reason I decided to start at the start and so I spend the whole day reading about network architecture, different models, layers of TCP/IP and stuff. Came across something called REST APIs. Now, upon reading I understand what REST APIs are on a fundamental level. But one question that I can't seem to answer is so then are all, essentially, web services, RESTful, or are there other styles of architecture too to build a web app?

Comment: `REST APIs are on a fundamental level` - they aren't. They are [a way of using HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5449043/11683). So no, the use of HTTP does not imply the use of REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does everything on the World Wide Web use REST?

Sort of.

REST is an [architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/software_arch.htm#sec_1_5), the "coordinated set of architectural constraints" used in the development of the HTTP 1.1 standard in the 1990s.  Notice that Roy Fielding, who describes [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm)in the dissertation he published in 2000, is also the first author listed in [RFC 2616](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616) (and more recently, [RFC 7230](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230)).

In [chapter six](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_2_5) of his dissertation, Fielding observes:

> Like most real-world systems, not all components of the deployed Web architecture obey every constraint present in its architectural design.

The tracking of client application state is a common example; the web, as it is today, doesn't offer us a common, general purpose mechanism for tracking state in our clients.  So instead, web designers resort to tracking that state on the server, either by using resources specific to a user (see [REST mismatches in URI](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_2_5)) or by using cookies as a hidden mechanism for tracking history on the server (see [REST mismatches in HTTP](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_3_4_2)).

In other words, the web we use every day isn't a perfect expression of the REST architectural style.

Further more, you have ideas like [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) or [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/), where important semantic information about a message is *not* expressed in a standardized form, which means that our general purpose components cannot assess the semantics of the messages and take intelligent actions.

---

> are all, essentially, web services, RESTful

No - not unless you limit yourself to a definition of "web services" that excludes implementations that violate REST.

Finding web implementations that are architecturally aligned with remote procedure calls, rather than REST, is common.  See [Fielding 2008](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven).  Special note: *read the comments*, which contain a lot of useful Q and A.